# Lower bound for $\text{ord}_{pq} a$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd prime numbers and $\gcd(a, pq)=1$. Is there an expression for lower bound of order of $a$ modulo $pq$?

I know that with the given conditions we have$$a^{\text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$I was looking for something like $\text{ord}_{pq} a \ge\text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$. I know this is not true! I just wanted to give an example for what  I am looking for.

Comment: This is kind of a weird question.  The order of $a$ modulo $pq$ is exactly *equal* to the LCM of the orders of $a$ modulo $p$ and $q$, respectively.  Wouldn't it be more fruitful to just ask for a lower bound for the prime case?

Comment: You are right. That would be a better question to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be any bound; take $a=1$, the order is $1$. If you find this trivial, take $a= pq-1$, the order is $2$.

Generally, the condition $\gcd(a,pq)=1$ only means that the class is invertible. The structure of the group of invertible classes is  well known. 
In this case we know this (multiplicative) is isomorphic to 
$C_{p-1} \times C_{q-1}$ and further to $C_{\gcd(p-1,q-1)} \times C_{\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)}$. So any divisor of $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ will be the order of some $a$.

Of course there is only one element of order $1$, and there are three elements of order $2$. If we somehow exclude those, then the order will be bounded below by the smallest divisor greater than $2$ of $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$.

Comment: How about $a$ being an odd number greater than $1$ or other condition on $p$ or $q$ or $a$?

Comment: I included some more discussion.